# Jquery wrap all bug Firefox

Tags: jquery, html, function, firefox

i have script, that contains function `wrapAll`.

```
function wr() {
  var classes = $('[class^=itcalss]').map(function() {
    return $(this).attr('class');
  });

  // Filter only unique ones
  var uniqueClasses = $.unique(classes);

  // Now group them
  $(uniqueClasses).each(function(i, v) {
    $('.' + v).wrapAll('<div class ="wrapp-' + v + '"><div class ="parent-' + v + '"></div></div>');
  });
}
setTimeout(wr, 2000);
```

In Chrome works perfect , as expected, for ex. all divs with class `itcalss-good` are wrapped div with class `parent-itcalss-good` and `wrapp-itcalss-good`.

But in FIREFOX it works bad...as also expected... so i don't understand why, but wrapAll divs are duplicated ``` wrapp-itcalss-good``parent-itcalss-good``wrapp-itcalss-good``parent-itcalss-good ``` and only then goes my divs with class  `itcalss-good`

I don't understand WHY...Help me please!

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {

    function wr() {
      var classes = $('[class^=itcalss]').map(function() {
        return $(this).attr('class');
      });

      // Filter only unique ones
      var uniqueClasses = $.unique(classes);

      // Now group them
      $(uniqueClasses).each(function(i, v) {


        $('.' + v).wrapAll('<div class ="wrapp-' + v + '"><div class ="parent-' + v + '"></div></div>');
      });
    }
    setTimeout(wr, 500);
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
[class^=itcalss] {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin: 10px 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
[class^=parent] {
padding:10px;
  border:2px solid red;
}
[class^=wrapp] {
padding:10px;
  border:2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="itcalss-azbuka">text1</div>
<div class="itcalss-azbuka">text2</div>
<div class="itcalss-azbuka">text3</div>
<div class="itcalss-azbuka">text4</div>

<div class="itcalss-kaka">kaka1</div>
<div class="itcalss-kaka">kaka2</div>
<div class="itcalss-kaka">kaka3</div>
<div class="itcalss-kaka">kaka4</div>
```

Strange...but works good in FIREFOX...i don't understand...

Problem have not resolved for my site... any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide a live demo that we can see and test?